# Lazy Attribute Coercion

Tags: perl, moose, lazy-evaluation

With [Moose](http://search.cpan.org/~doy/Moose-2.0602/lib/Moose.pm), you can have `lazy` `builders` on attributes, where the builder is called when the attribute is first accessed *if the attribute was not already populated*. You can have type coercion of an attribute with `coerce`, but this is applied *whenever the attribute is set*, so even on object initialization.

I'm looking for a way to implement **lazy coercion**, where an attribute may be initially populated, but is only coerced when it is first accessed. This is important when coercion is expensive.

In the following example, I use a union type and method modifiers to do this:

```
package My::Foo;
use Moose;
has x => (
    is => 'rw',
    isa => 'ArrayRef | Int',
    required => 1
);

around "x" => sub {
    my $orig = shift;
    my $self = shift;
    my $val = $self->$orig(@_);
    unless(ref($val)) {
        # Do the cocerion
        $val = [ map { 1 } 1..$val ];
        sleep(1); # in my case this is expensive
    }
    return $val;
}; 
1;

my $foo = My::Foo->new( x => 4 );
is_deeply $foo->x, [ 1, 1, 1, 1 ], "x converted from int to array at call time";
```

However there are a few problems with this:

1. I dislike the *union type* + *method modifier* approach. It goes against the "Best Practices" suggestion to [use coercion instead of unions](http://search.cpan.org/~doy/Moose-2.0602/lib/Moose/Manual/BestPractices.pod#Use_coercion_instead_of_unions). It isn't declarative.
2. I need to do this with *many* attributes across *many* classes. Therefore some form of DRY is needed. This could be meta-attribute roles, type-coercion, what have you.

**Update:**
I followed [ikegami's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/589924/ikegami) suggestion to encapsulate the expensive type coercion inside an object and provide an outer coercion to this object:

```
package My::ArrayFromInt;
use Moose;
use Moose::Util::TypeConstraints;
subtype 'My::ArrayFromInt::Inner',
    as 'ArrayRef[Int]';
coerce 'My::ArrayFromInt::Inner',
    from 'Int',
    via { return [ (1) x $_ ] };
has uncoerced => (is => 'rw', isa => 'Any', required => 1); 
has value => (
    is      => 'rw',
    isa     => 'My::ArrayFromInt::Inner',
    builder => '_buildValue',
    lazy    => 1,
    coerce  => 1
);
sub _buildValue {
    my ($self) = @_; 
    return $self->uncoerced;
}
1;
package My::Foo;
use Moose;
use Moose::Util::TypeConstraints;
subtype 'My::ArrayFromInt::Lazy' => as class_type('My::ArrayFromInt');
coerce 'My::ArrayFromInt::Lazy',
    from 'Int',
    via { My::ArrayFromInt->new( uncoerced => $_ ) };
has x => (
    is => 'rw',
    isa => 'My::ArrayFromInt::Lazy',
    required => 1,
    coerce => 1
);
1;
```

This works if `$foo->x->value` is called. However this doesn't solve point #2, as I would need to create `My::ArrayFromInt` and the `::Lazy` subtype for each attribute I would like to transform. And I'd like to avoid calling `$foo->x->value` if possible.

Comment: If there are two ways of representing a datum, one should be able to get either representations. Coerce into an object, then fetch the data from the object in the format you want. [Example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10506416/can-i-use-an-attribute-modifer-in-moose-in-a-base-class-to-handle-multiple-attri/10508753#10508753)

Comment: s/ `map { 1 } 1..$val` / `(1) x $val` /

Comment: @ikegami The problem is that coercion is expensive; I only want to perform it if the attribute is being asked for.

Comment: That's why I said to coerce to an object (that has a getter that does the coercion) instead of doing the expensive coercion.

Answer (score 0):

How about having the typedef along the lines described, then doing

```
has _x => (
    is       => 'ro',
    isa      => 'Int|MyArrayOfInts',
    init_arg => 'x',
    required => 1,
);

has x => (
    is => 'ro',
    lazy => 1,
    isa => 'MyArrayOfInts',
    coerce => 1,
    default => sub { $_[0]->_x },
);
```

It'd make sense to wrap that up into some kind of helper method to create the pair of objects along the lines of

```
has_lazily_coerced x => (
    is => 'ro',
    isa => 'TargetType',
);
```

which would introspect on TargetType to get a list of legal types for the uncoerced shadow attribute and generate the pair of attributes for you.